# Avoid duplicating disconnected entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is what I have :

Domain model :

```
public class MyDomainEntity1 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { set; set; }
}

public class MyDomainEntity2
{
    public Entity1 {get; set;}
    public string Entity1Name {get; set;}
    public string SomeIrrelevantProps {get; set;}
}
```

Context :

```
protected override OnModelBuilding(modelbuilder)
{
    modelbuilder.Entity<MyDomainEntity1>().HasKey(x=> x.Name);
    modelbuilder.Entity<MyDomainEntity2>().HasRequired(x=> x.Entity1).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(x=> x.Entity1Name);
}
```

Seeding code :

```
context.Entities1DbSet.AddOrUpdate(x=>x.Name, new { Name = "ReferentialName1" });
context.Entities1DbSet.AddOrUpdate(x=>x.Name, new { Name = "ReferentialName2" });
context.SaveChanges(); // up to this point Working fine even when called several time.

context.Entities2DbSet.Add( new MyDomainEntity2 { Entity1 = new MyDomainEntity1 { Name = "ReferentialName1"}, Entity1Name = "ReferentialName1" });
context.SaveChanges() // throws the following exception :
```

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.MyDomainEntity1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MyDomainEntity1'. The duplicate key value is (ReferentialName1).
>   The statement has been terminated.

For some reason EF tries to add a new MyDomainEntity1 instead of using the entry already existing in the database. I used this pattern without ANY problem up to now. It seems that EF was automatically attaching the new entities I was adding thus linking them to the already existing row in the DB.

However for some reason it stopped working and I'm getting the error I have now. I use this pattern a lot in my domain model to refer to referential data by simply instantiating a class. I can't see what I've changed to break it.

Any idea ?

Please note that calling DbSet.Attach() is not an option for me. The instantiations of MyDomainEntity1 are usually done in my domain model project where I don't have access to the DB.

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: @Colin Thank you,  I agree this applies perfectly to my situation but I forgot to mention one detail in my sample because I'm actually doing what Julie is talking about : "Save the Grief and Use That Foreign Key : Rather than setting the navigation property and having to worry about the state of the Topic, just set the TopicId [the foreign key] property." This is precisely what I am doing so it should work... And indeed it used to work. I'll update my sample to outline it.

Comment: *Please note that calling DbSet.Attach() is not an option for me* then you're doing it wrong.  You have to tell EF one of two ways that it needs to track the entity and how.  You can attach it in a modified state, or you can pull it from the database (which attaches it) and then make changes (which marks it modified).  If you don't do either of these you can't expect EF to know how it should handle `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: You are using `context.Entities2DbSet.Add` instead of `context.Entities2DbSet.AddOrUpdate`?

Comment: @Yuck Yes you can, please check Colin's link. You just have to set the foreign key and EF will figure this out.